# New CO/ALR vs AlumiConn connectors for outdoor outlet

Tags: wiring, outdoor

I want to replace an existing outdoor duplex outlet at my house.  The house was built in the 70s and has aluminum wiring.  The outlet is at the end of the circuit run, so the aluminum wires are directly connected to the outlet terminals (no pigtail).  Note that I cannot find weather resistant (WR) CO/ALR outlets.  So, when I replace this outlet, am I better off connecting the aluminum wires to the terminals of a new non-WR CO/ALR outlet, or using a new WR outlet with AlumiConn connectors and copper pigtails?  I've seen other posts on this site that ask a similar question for indoor applications...and the highest rated answer says that CO/ALR is a better solution than AlumiConn.  My application is outdoors, though, so a consideration of my question is weighing the WR vs. non-WR for outdoor use against CO/ALR and non-CO/ALR for aluminum wiring.

Comment: IIRC @Harper has a favorite toy for this sort of thing which is effectively a miniature Polaris connector, as opposed ot the AlumiConns. MAC-Blocks seems to be it, on a quick search.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- well, the ALumiConns fit the description of "miniature Polaris connector", but yes, MAC-Blocks are kind of their evolved form

Comment: @Ecnerwal Oh, I got MAC Blocks from ThreePhaseEel :)  However their winning characteristic is being able to take #6 wire, or, >=4 smaller wires.  For 2-3 #10-14 you might as well stay with Alumiconns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alumiconns wether screw type or wire nut will be safer, and better than going to a non co/alr fixture.
The fixture would need to be a GFCI fixture or protected by a GFCI device upstream

note not to be a pain but this fixture would normally require tamper resistant features most internet electricians don’t keep up on that. There are many listed alumacons most are purple and wire nut or screw type they both do the job converting to copper for a non listed co/alr device.

Comment: The outlet is wired to the load terminals of an upstream GFCI outlet, so its protected.  And I am aware of tamper resistance (TR).  Whether required or not, I was going to do TR just to keep curious kids safe.  So I'm truly debating between a CO/ALR outlet and a TWR (tamper and weather resistant) outlet with AlumiConns.  (I was just trying to keep my original post simple by not including "tamper" verbiage.)  I can't find an outlet that is TWR and CO/ALR...so I'm forced to pick between one or the other.